# Quadratic equation solver in php

Tags: php, formula, calculator, equation, quadratic

I tried to make a quadratic equation solver in php:

**index.html:**

```
<html>
    <body>
        <form action="findx.php" method="post">
            Find solution for ax^2 + bx + c<br>
            a: <input type="text" name="a"><br>
            b: <input type="text" name="b"><br>
            c: <input type="text" name="c"><br>
            <input type="submit" value="Find x!">
        </form>   
    </body>
</html>
```

**findx.php:**

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['a'])){ $a = $_POST['a']; } 
    if(isset($_POST['b'])){ $b = $_POST['b']; } 
    if(isset($_POST['c'])){ $c = $_POST['c']; }

    $d = $b*$b - 4*$a*$c;
    echo $d;

    if($d < 0) {
        echo "The equation has no real solutions!";
    } elseif($d = 0) {
        echo "x = ";
        echo (-$b / 2*$a);
    } else  {
        echo "x1 = ";
        echo ((-$b + sqrt($d)) / (2*$a));
        echo "<br>";
        echo "x2 = ";
        echo ((-$b - sqrt($d)) / (2*$a));
    }
?>
```

the problem is that it's returning wrong answers (d is right,x1 and x2 are not) seems like sqrt() is returning zero or maybe something else.

Comment: What results did you get for what input parameters? And what did you expect?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a typo in this line:

`elseif($d = 0)`

which is *assigning* the value `0` to `$d` instead of comparing it. That means you are always evaluating `sqrt(0)`, which is 0, in your `else` block.

It should be:

`elseif($d == 0)`

Comment: In languages where such assignments doesn't give at least a warning, a useful habit is to put the constant on the left: `if (0 = $d)` will fail.